# Hyperlinks behaving unusually

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Using Wordpress and the  tag I have three separate footers, it is important to have three individual footer template and styles because each footer acts accordingly to the page it is on. Two out of three footers work just fine however one of them acts quite differently for a number of reasons, for example it adds hyperlinks where they are not present and also adds a different style, in this case a purple color, which I believe is 'visited'.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I have pasted the code below ..

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li class="photo"><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/full/example-02.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="photo"><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/full/example-01.jpg"/></li>
    <li class="photo"><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/full/example-03.jpg"/></li>
</ul>

<div id="bx-pager-wrapper">
  <div id="bx-pager">
    <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    02.jpg"/>
    <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    01.jpg"/>
    <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    03.jpg"/>
  </div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});
  });
</script>

<footer id="footer-gallery">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">      
      <ul>
        <li>2013 Paul Crowe</li>
        <li>Created by <a href="http://liamhodnett.com">Liam Hodnett</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do apologise, here is a link to the working footer http://chefpaulcrowe.com/ and here is a link to the broken footer http://chefpaulcrowe.com/gallery/ I will amend my original question with code attached.

Comment: @jmore009 it might be worth mentioning that besides the div id and classes the html for both footers are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have it now, you're going to have to do some more reordering. so first put remove `#example` and put those styles back on `bx-pager-wrapper`. Now take `bx-pager-wrapper` and put it inside `bx-wrapper` it should go at the very bottom right before the close tag for `bx-wrapper`. Next set `bx-wrapper` to `position: relative` in your CSS. Leave the footer where it is and that SHOULD work.

**EDIT**

---

Also remove `overflow-y: hidden;` on the `#gallery`

ok, looks like the issue is none of those `a` tags below are closed. It's pretty much that simple haha Unfortunately the console always shows them as closed so I didn't see that. You can probably put everything back to the way it was originally and just close those tags

```
<div id="bx-pager-wrapper">
    <div id="bx-pager">
    <a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    02.jpg"/>
    <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    01.jpg"/>
    <a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://chefpaulcrowe.com/img/gallery/thumb/example-    03.jpg"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: OKAAAAY .. so thats done! No progress as of yet though, could you just check my HTML I think that is right (its always the little problems right ha!) @jmore009

Comment: ok close, dont add another `bx-wrapper` there is already one in your html so just put `bx-pager-wrapper` inside the current one. Then set `bx-wrapper` to `position: absolute` and then take out `overflow-y:hidden;` on `#gallery` in your css

Comment: Amended, however I have done a search using Safari and I can't seem to find a #bx-wrapper in my current HTML @jmore009 ...

Comment: ah gotcha, ok its this JS plugin thats appending things so its hard for me to see, but im determined to get this working at this point haha so give me a little time, im going to set this up on my own and figure it out.

Comment: No problem my friend, Im going to revert back to where we were so I don't give my client the fright of his life :) I look forward to hearing from you @jmore009 and thanks you once again!

Comment: hey can you post the HTML exactly as it is currently? I think I may have found the issue

Comment: Thanks @jmore009 I have just edited my original question with the HTML markup as it is at the moment :) thanks again!

Comment: Starting from 'Also remove overflow-y: hidden; on the #gallery' correct ?? @jmore009

Comment: hahahaha problem solved !!!! I need to open my eyes a lot more :) Thanks so much for your help you've been fantastic! Are you on Twitter ?? @jmore009

Comment: no problem, i probably should have just looked at your HTML to begin with haha no I dont use twitter, im online too much as it is, i try not to spend it all on social media haha But you can do me a favor and just check this answer off as solved.

Comment: I see no problem :) well thanks again anyway! I was going to give to give you a bit of a Twitter shout out thats all! And of course I will

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett Hey I didn't get notified of this response. Thanks for checking this off. I work for a web design company in NYC, you could shout me out there, {at}nycdevshop, im Jesse M. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

you have `<footer id="footer-gallery">` inside of `<div id="bx-pager-wrapper">` which appears to apply an `a` tag with `data-slide-index="2"`. Try taking `footer-gallery` out of that `bx-pager-wrapper` div.

**UPDATE**

Try this, I'm guessing that your JS is looking for an ID of `bx-pager-wrapper` but wrap that and the footer in a `div` (call it whatever you want) and remove the styles from `bx-pager-wrapper` and add them to this new div instead:

```
#example{
    width: 100%;
    height: 142px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(/img/pager-wrapper.png) repeat-x;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Right now that footer is kind of dependent on the styles of `bx-pager-wrapper` but it can't be inside so this might help preserve the style but not apply those `a`s

**LETS HOPE THIRD TIMES A CHARM**

Ok so keep the `example` div set up, add all of the same styles as `bx-pager-wrapper`. Next, for `bx-pager-wrapper` only leave `height: 142px` and `width: 100%` make sure you take the footer out so the footer and `bx-pager-wrapper` are siblings, then remove `margin-top: 172px;` from the footer.

[image: EXAMPLE]

You dont have the styles applied to example and you need to reorder the `footer` and `bx-page-wrapper`

[image: New Image]

Comment: I'm 99% sure you are along the right lines, I just need to fathom out exactly where to put the footer with the bx-pager-wrapper breaking it, thanks!

Comment: when I take the footer and put it (quite obscurely) above the header, all the links, all the styles, work perfectly so I know it must be a problem with the footer being inside the 'bx-page-wrapper' like you suggested. I am however missing a closing </div> from this bx-wrapper, only when I add it in, the footer disappears completely! I'm a little lost ha!

Comment: Thanks again @jmore009 I will give it a shot now, appreciate all the help :)

Comment: No go I am afraid, removing the styles from bx-pager-wrapper removes it completely, adding the styles to the new #example div has no effect on the footer, I could add a and a:hover commands to the #bx-pager-wrapper classes however this won't effect the hyperlinks that should not be there.

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett i updated my answer again, try that, it works in the console and it should remove the links when it's live

Comment: The bx-pager-wrapper which controls the slideshow navigation also using an called bx-pager, I have however noticed that one ending </div> IS missing, however when this is inserted, the footer disappears completely, could this be anything to do with what is causing the problem @jmore009

Comment: No luck once again I'm afraid @jmore0099 when you say 'take the footer out' you mean take it out of the #example div correct? I can see the logic but for some reason this is actually removing the entire #bx-pager-wrapper, which is what controls the slideshow navigation

Comment: i mean keep it in the example but take it out of bx-page-wrapper. The two of those should be contained inside of example. and example needs all of the styles that bx-page-wrapper had

Comment: I am a little confused (bare with me) I have added my HTML markup to my original question, are we on the same page ?? @jmore009

Comment: i see what you did on that page, it looks like it's all good, the links aren't there, you just need the styles I posted above to your css for `#example` and that whole section should show up again. and you need to switch the order of the footer and bx-page-wrapper, footer should come after

Comment: so I have followed your instructions, including the css styles, and it appears that the footer and also the bx-pager-wrapper are gone leaving only the header and slideshow, I am stumped! ha! @jmore009

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett check out the screenshot above and let me know if that helps, open it in a new tab to see it bigger. I'm not sure if you added the styles to example but they are not showing up

Comment: I can't express how much I appreciate all your help! Using your Developer Tools would it be possible to click those little arrows after each ID so I can see the full code working? I would really really appreciate that

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett ok check out the new screenshot and see if that makes sense

Comment: Ok! I think I have the HTML markup correct now (Im 99% sure anyway) I have #example and its styles in my .css stylesheet, I can't understand why you can't see it .. strange @jmore009

Comment: yeah the HTML looks good, but the links are there so you might have to put the footer first after all since it looks like anything under that wrapper class is getting tagged. But ignore that for now. I looked at your css and it looks like there is an extra `}` on `#billboard .gallery-image` which is right above your `#example` that's probably what's killing the styles, remove that extra `}` and try again

Comment: Schoolboy error huh! So the random } has been removed and we have the slider navigation and footer back however these annoying links are STILL there, persistent little buggers! I will try what you said and put the footer first :) Thanks again @jmore009

Comment: We are so close I can feel the victory! Could you have a look now @jmore009 what do you make of that?

Comment: yeah it's close, im going to take a look at the JS and see if something can be changed

Comment: Thanks @jmore009 I REALLY appreciate all the help! If you were this side of the Atlantic I would buy you a beer

Comment: haha no problem, im going to post as a new answer, this one is a mess

Comment: Sounds like a plan! :D